# What missions have vault doors which require a vault access card?

Tags: invisible-inc

### Intro

In Invisible Inc, there are Vault Access Cards that can be used to open vault doors in financial missions, where you basically rob a bank.

However, I'm currently doing a cyberlab mission, where I get to install free augments or augment sockets on my agents. I always thought that there were always only 2 augment stations in these missions, but this time I noticed that there was a vault door(!), and after peaking behind the vault door, I noticed that there were an additional 2 augment stations!

Here is a screenshot. Note that the 4th augment station is hidden behind the tooltip.

[image]

### Question

Do cyberlab missions always have this vault door, protecting an extra 2 augment stations? Or do the extra stations only spawn sometimes?

Finally, do other non-financial missions also sometimes have these vault doors which require a vault access card?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have only seen a door that requires a vault access card of Vault and Cyberlab missions. Your suspicion is correct that Cyberlabs do not always have an extra two Augment Grafters, I don't know what the likelihood of their appearance is.

Additionally, if you are playing Endless mode you can reach a point where the exit teleporter on every mission will also be blocked by a vault door (For me this was around day 5 on the default "endless" difficulty). While there is a key card hidden somewhere in these missions that will unlock the door (and I assume, like the normal passcards, probably won't transfer between missions), I believe you could substitute in a vault access card if you have one.

Comment: Have you tried using a Vault card for an Exit card? The vault card has "password was just 123" line, the Exit card says "password is a secure 1024 bit key" so it seems... more professional, and not interchangable.

Comment: I have not, but actually a quick bit of research turns up [this bug report](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/53870-gameplay-endless-left-chief-financial-suite-with-exit-access-card/) that indicates that Vault keys can be used on elevator exit doors, and it is intentional.

Comment: I have also only seen Vault Doors in Vault and Cyberlab missions. I had one with me on a cyberlab mission and the machine behind the vault door on that mission was a drill instead; it could remove a implant instead. (IIRC it could alternatively add a slot)